# strings out of bounds

Tags: overflow

This was the original code

```
int main(void)
{
char hello[] = "hello ", world[] = "world!\n", *s;
s = strcat(hello,world);
printf(s);
return 0;
}




char hello[] = "hello ", world[] = "world!\n", *s;
strcat(hello,world);
printf(hello);
```

i changed it to what it is below

i am positive i fixed that code, but my instructor marked me off.
like i told him it doesn't even use the pointer, so this is fine. he said he doesn't think it's correct

am i wrong?
like i ran it 50 times and it still works.

Comment: If I were your instructor, I would mark you down just for declaring multiple variables of different types on the same line.

Comment: hello[] = "hello " is same as declaring  hello[7] = "hello ". In strcat you are going out of bounds

Comment: not my code, just changed it.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site. Too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor is correct.  `hello` is only big enough to hold 6 characters (plus a null-terminator).  So trying to `strcat` something into it writes past the end, causing undefined behaviour.